Find the area of the region specified as "below $y=3x$, above $y=0$, from $x=0$ to $x=3$".
The problem:
Find the area of the region specified as "below $y=3x$, above $y=0$, from $x=0$ to $x=3$".
The solution:
$\frac{3}{2}$ sq. units
What I have tried:
The chapter this problem is from is called "Areas as Limits of Sums", so I tried solving it with the method used in one of the example problems.
I divide the interval $[0,3]$ into $n$ equal subintervals of length $\Delta x=\frac{3}{n}$.
$x_i=\frac{3i}{n}$ for $i=0, 1, 2, ..., n$.
At each $x=x_i$, the height $y_i$ of the rectangle is:
$y_i=3 \cdot x_i = 3 \cdot \frac{3i}{n}=\frac{9i}{n}$
Area of the $i$-th rectangle $=y_i \cdot \Delta x = \frac{9i}{n} \cdot \frac{3}{n}=\frac{27i}{n^2}$
I sum the areas of all $n$ rectangles to approximate the total area.
$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{27i}{n^2}=\frac{27}{n^2} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{27}{n^2} \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{27(n+1)}{2n}$$
The required area $A$ is given by
$$A=\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{27(n+1)}{2n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{27 \cdot n \cdot (1+\frac{1}{n})}{n \cdot 2}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{27(1+\frac{1}{n})}{2}=\frac{27 \cdot 1}{2}=\frac{27}{2}$$
My questions:
Why am I not getting the right solution? What am I doing wrong?

$27/2$ seems correct. It's a triangle with base $3$ and height $9$.

Alright, I guess the book's wrong.

Your attempt at solving this problem has absolutely nothing wrong with it. All steps and calculations were done correctly. It appears the book you are using has an error.
One way you can easily see that your answer is correct is by seeing what the question looks like on a graph

You are basically solving the area of this triangle with a base of $3$ and height of $9$. Of course, the area is $\frac{27}{2}$ as you suggested.
